# Namespace Error: Error CS0234 - 'UnityWebRequest'

Tags: php, mysql, unity-game-engine, namespaces, server-error

I'm creating a registration page on Unity and this error keeps appearing. It requested me to use the UnityWebRequest and once I added it, this message keeps coming up. "error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'UnityWebRequest' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEngine' (are you missing an assembly reference?)".

This the first time using this application and have been following this tutorial  step by step and theirs has no error.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4W90-mh70JY

This is the link to the tutorial I have been following. And below is my code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.UnityWebRequest;

public class Registration : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputField nameField;
    public InputField passwordField;

    public Button submitButton;

    public void CallRegister()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Register());
    }

    IEnumerator Register() 
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("name", nameField.text);
        form.AddField("password", passwordField.text);
        WWW www = new WWW("http://localhost/sqlconnect/register.php", form);
        yield return www;
        if (www.text == "0")
        {
            Debug.Log("User created successfully.");
            UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("User Creation failed. Error #" + www.text);
        }
    }

    public void VerifyInputs()
    {
        submitButton.interactable = (nameField.text.Length >= 8 && passwordField.text.Length >= 8);
    }
}
```

[Picture of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLcyg.png)

[Picture of my Assets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zL9FC.png)

Does this have an issue with my server? If not, can you identify the issue and error?

Comment: Www was deprecated a long time ago. Thats why

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all your tutorial seems to be quite old (Unity 2017).

Even then there is and never was a namespace called `UnityEngine.UnityWebRequest`.

[`UnityWebRequest`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html) is and has always been in the namespace `UnityEngine.Networking`.

So

```
using UnityEngine.UnityWebRequest;
```

makes no sense and if anything it should rather be

```
using UnityEngine.Networking;
```

---

Besides that you should not use the deprecated [`WWW`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) (which btw anyway is and was directly in the namespace `UnityEngine`) anymore at all but rather [`UnityWebRequest.Post`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html)